# Flutter GetX and Get Storage Error type: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> after anonymous closure

Tags: flutter, get

I am facing an error that after Googling is pretty common but I didn't find a similar code to mine since I am using GetX and Get Storage.
So, I am building a simple (not for me since I am new to Flutter) Shopping List app (basically a todo app), when I add an item to the list is perfectly added to the memory BUt if I go back on the stack with Get.back() and then I open again the ShoppingScreen again I face the error.

****This is the console message:****

The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'ShoppingList' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

The relevant error-causing widget was
GetMaterialApp
lib\main.dart:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

#0      ShoppingListController.onInit.

package:one_place_all_notes/controllers/shopping_list_controller.dart:19

#1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:411:31)

#2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:340:26)

#3      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:188:27)

#4      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)

**This is the class:**

```
class ShoppingList {
String text;
bool done;

ShoppingList({this.text, this.done = false});

factory ShoppingList.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ShoppingList(
text: json['text'],
done: json['done'],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
data['text'] = this.text;
return data;
}
}
```

**And here is the controller where the error occurs:**

```
class ShoppingListController extends GetxController {
var shoppings = <ShoppingList>[].obs;

@override
void onInit() {
List storedShoppings = GetStorage().read<List>('shoppings');

if (storedShoppings != null) {
shoppings = storedShoppings
.map((e) => ShoppingList.fromjson(e))
.toList().obs;
}
```

Comment: Might help to show how you're storing it and then the page that you go back to when the error occurs. When you restart the does everything in your `onInit` run without problems?

Comment: Thanks for commenting but in the end, I solved the problem on my own, see the Answer below..

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a few hours I solved the problem. I don't know if it is the right way but it worked.

In the onPressed function that pop the screen with Get.back(); I also added another GetX method, the Get.appUpdate();

Because I noticed that after a hot reload I didn't have issues, forcing the app to update
solved the problem for me. But if there are better solutions I am glad to hear them.